# Declare integer as null

Tags: c#, .net

Generally, we delare variable property like this:

```
int a = 0;
```

I want to declare one **integer as null**. how can I do that?

my expected output is

```
int i = null;
```

Comment: Before getting into how to do something *like* this - do you understand why you can't do what you've asked for just as it is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> C# Data types are divided into value types and reference type. By default
>   value types are not nullable. But for reference type is null.

```
string name = null;
Int ? i = null; // declaring nullable type
```

If you want to make value type as nullable use `?`

```
Int j = i;  //this will through the error because implicit conversion of nullable 
            // to non nullable is not possible `
```

Use

```
int j =i.value;
```

or

```
int j =(int) i;
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [`Nullable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) type:

```
int? i = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Value types in c# are not-nullable unless you explicitly define them as such. If you want to allow nulls for an int you have to declare your variable like so:

```
int? i = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

An integer is a value type, whose default value, when initialized, is 0.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx

You just cannot make it null, and the compiler will not let you use an uninitialized integer.

If you require a null to be assigned to an integer, for whatever reason, you should use a reference type Nullable. int? = null . I hope this helps.